# A way to send data from server to js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently started a project and I need to transform data from the server-side (node.js) to my js file (on the client-side I am using a regular js). Is there any way to do this?

server:

```
app.get('/start', function (req, res) {
console.log("enter");
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'enter.html'));
});

app.post('/start', function (req, res) {
const userName = req.body.userName;
const userPassword = req.body.password;

User.findOne({ userName: userName }, function (err, foundUser) {
    if (foundUser === null) { //the subject doesnt exist yet
        const newUser = new User({
            userName: userName,
            userPassword: userPassword,
        });
        newUser.save();
    } else {
        res.status(200).send({ message: "Hello!" });
    }
});
});
```

I want to get the message via the js file (in the client)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code do you have so far?

Comment: You can try ajax method to get the data from server.

Comment: can you please guide me to where look for it?

Comment: and I added the server code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
fetch('/start', {
  method: 'POST', 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({username : 'test'}),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: in the //response here I need to get the info from the massege from the server?

Comment: There are two types to connect with server 1. form submit (in html) and 2. Js ajax request(in js). What you want?

Comment: is there any way to get the text from {"message":"Hello!"}? and to get only the "hello"?

Comment: You get the < {"message":"Hello!"}> this message on <data> variable